# Web Scraping : Request Error - ('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))

Tags: python, ssl, web-scraping, httprequest, connection-timeout

I'm trying to webscrape the data (bit huge amount) using a json link request.

```
    data = []
    for cid in (lookup['CID'].unique()) :
        req_url = "https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug_view/data/compound/{0}/JSON".format(cid)
        response = requests.get(req_url)
        data.append(response.json())
```

I'm testing this(this is a part of Azure function) locally via command prompt. So I get the error like below while I checked the status of the code running:

> "output":"{"Error": "('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))"}"

Before that in between, while I was installing some requirements, I got some errors with packages and dependencies:

> WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.

Please suggest a solution.